# Find application mode, is it idle or not, in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me, midp, httpconnection, rms

I want to send stored RMS data using an HTTP connection when the application is in idle mode.

So if the user is not doing anything with the application at that time, my thread will invoke and send RMS data to server.

For this requirement, how do I how find out if the application in active mode or idle mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait for the backlight to go off, if that's enough of an indication of whether the application is active.

Implement the [SystemListener2 interface](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html), there's a method backlightStateChange() that will be invoked after the object is registered with [Application](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html).addSystemListener

Comment: thanks for your reply i want to implement this in j2me for nokia e-72 and what the solution you suggested is perfect for blackberry. which api's i can use for j2me??

Comment: @Mihir Why did you add the BlackBerry tag?

Comment: because i want to implement it on both j2me mobiles and blackberry so if code are standard j2me code then that will work on both mobiles

Comment: @Mihir I do BlackBerry development, so can't really comment on the more general j2me API.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any smarter solution than using `Displayable.setCommandListener(CommandListener l)`.

The command listener should use Timer. When a certain timeout (let's say 60 seconds) is expired, the timer task should run and trigger sending your data. I think that if you have access to the midlet's code, this solution is not so bad.

Comment: can you explain briefly or give some example so that i can understand.