# How can I sense if a phone is in standby or sleep mode(dor Nokia)?

Tags: java-me, nokia

I need to sense a phone's status. If it is sleep or standby mode I have to change my app's running code (to save power consumption). Is this supported by the JavaME API? ( for Nokias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Its difficult to achieve with j2me. But see this [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920220/j2me-find-application-mode-is-it-idle-or-not). Here AlexR said the one solution. you can try like that. May be it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, [`MIDlet.pauseApp()`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/midlet/MIDlet.html#pauseApp%28%29) gets called when the phone enters sleep/standby mode. Not sure about that, but it shouldn't be hard to check if this works.